# Invalid signature on Adobe Reader: "signer's identity has not yet been verified"

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, signature, node-forge

I've tried with several p12 certificates and when I sign via my Nodejs approach it returns an invalid signature on Adobe.

[image]

However, signing just with Adobe the signature seems to be valid (just with a warning).

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing?

```
const signer = require('node-signpdf')
const fs = require('fs')
const helpers = require('node-signpdf/dist/helpers')

const init = async () => {
    const p12Buffer = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/cert.p12`);

    let pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/test.pdf`);
        pdfBuffer = helpers.plainAddPlaceholder({
        pdfBuffer,
        signatureLength: 31280,
    });

    pdfBuffer = signer.default.sign(pdfBuffer, p12Buffer, {
        passphrase: 'reingenio'
    });

    fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/signed.pdf`, pdfBuffer)
}

init()
```

Thanks.

Comment: having same issue, need help

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried read the pdf file as binary ?
fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/test.pdf`, 'binary');